# Controller tests fail when ran together, pass when ran individually. How can this be?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I have some tests that require the user to be logged in. When I run the controller test by itself, it passes, and everything is green. If I run `rspec spec/controllers` some of my tests are failing with errors such as:

```
Failure/Error: get :my_modal, :format => :js
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `authenticate!' for nil:NilClass
```

Any tips how this could be fixed?

Comment: Is my answer possibly useful to you? If so, can you upvote it? Otherwise I'd prefer to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: would you like to share your _spec.rb file(s) that fails ?

Answer (score 0):

Once I had an error like this. Hence you do not share more details with us at the time I will tell you my story and hopefully you can find your error afterwards easier.

In my App 2 classes could log in. A "User" and a "Topic". I tried to make authentication, so users could only access user-related sites and topics could only access topic-related parts of the app.

One of the first errors i got, was your error. But i fixed it and will try to explain to you how I did. If a User was signed in, my app didn't know the authentification-methods related to the Topics. And vice versa if a Topic was signed in my app didn't know the User-related authentification-methods (I was asking for User.user_id or Topic.be_topic? to be true)

The clue to fix this problem was: I created a method called "user_signed_in" and ran the authentification over an IF method.

```
IF user_signed_in
  user.user_id > 0
ELSE
  topic.be_topic == true
END
```

hope that helps you out. I am new to Rails, please forgive my lack of deeper knowledge.